# How can I read a file to a string in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner. I'm trying to use the `markdown` library to convert mardown and insert it into a web page made with Blaze. I can do this:

```
readme :: Html
readme = do
  markdown def "#test"
```

Which works fine. But I can't do this:

```
readme :: Html
readme = do
  readmeFile <- readFile "../README.md"
  markdown def readmeFile
```

Because I get the errors:

```
Views/Home.hs:55:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM’
      Expected type: Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM String
        Actual type: IO String
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: readmeFile <- readFile "../README.md"
      In the expression:
        do { readmeFile <- readFile "../README.md";
             markdown def readmeFile }
      In an equation for ‘readme’:
          readme
            = do { readmeFile <- readFile "../README.md";
                   markdown def readmeFile }

Views/Home.hs:56:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
      Expected type: Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text
        Actual type: String
    • In the second argument of ‘markdown’, namely ‘readmeFile’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: markdown def readmeFile
      In the expression:
        do { readmeFile <- readFile "../README.md";
             markdown def readmeFile }
```

I know there's something simple to fix this, but I don't know where to start. [Here's the rest of my script](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/corpus-db/blob/9d64273a719b418a47e6d59835625d5325eae292/Views/Home.hs), if it helps to contextualize it. (It uses OverloadedStrings.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare the type `readme :: Html`, it means that `readme` will be a *pure value*, i.e. a proper constant. This is thus guaranteed to be the same each time you run the program – nice guarantee, but this also means you can't make it dependent on an external file, which could after all change at any time.

So what you want is probably this:

```
mkReadme :: IO Html
mkReadme = do
  readmeFile <- readFile "../README.md"
  return $ markdown def readmeFile
```

which works almost. Not quite because `readFile` generates an old-fashioned `String` while `markdown` wants the more efficient `Text` type. Easy to fix: just use the corresponding `readFile` function from the `text` library.

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as Txt

...

mkReadme :: IO Html
mkReadme = do
  readmeFile <- Txt.readFile "../README.md"
  return $ markdown def readmeFile
```

Comment: That makes the function work (although readFile is in Data.Text.Lazy.IO) but then when I try to use it somewhere, it gives me `expected type: Html; actual type: IO Html`. How can I make it just Html, and not IO Html?

Comment: You can't. If you read an external file, that's an IO action, no way around it. (That's not strictly speaking true, there are ways around it, but these are unidiomatic hacks that you don't want to use.) The real question you could well ask is: “how to _invoke_ such an `IO` action to actually use the generated Html in my program?”

Comment: I just want to import the contents of my README.md so I don't have to copy and paste the contents into my haskell file. There's no way to import the contents of an external file? Does a website's contents always have to be in an .hs file for it to be displayed using Blaze?

Comment: @Jono there are other ways to do this, read the file outside of this function, and pass the contents in as an argument to the function.  That way you don't need to do IO within the function.

Comment: @Jono it's possible to read in a file _at compile time_ using Template Haskell, i.e. basically you let the compiler paste the contents into your `.hs` file. But, in fact I'd argue it _is_ best to write everything in `.hs` files yourself, this way you're not bound to the limitation of formats like Markdown.

Comment: @Jono The issue is that the `readme :: Html` type promises that this is a constant value, not depending on external files/user input/network/etc. If you want to read a file, you need a different type. Doing otherwise requires either including the file inside the source code (possibly using Template Haskell?) or using ugly fragile hacks to lie to the compiler ("trust me, this is indeed a constant!"). Such lying is greatly discouraged, since unless used with great care, it can cause real disasters. In almost all cases, it also not needed at all.

Comment: If you want to take your `IO Html` as an argument to a pure function and have it return something else, like maybe `countWords :: Html -> Int`, you’d need to lift that function to one of type `:: IO Html -> IO Int`.  `Control.Monad.LiftM` might help, so you could write `liftM countWords`, or you could write a wrapper that calls the pure function with `do` notation: `do page <- iopage; return (countWords page)`

Comment: But what you really want to do is bind the result to a variable inside `main`, using `<-`, and then use it within that `do` block as though it were a pure variable.  That’s a lot better than propagating `IO` through the program to everything it touches.

Comment: @Davislor perhaps you should make that an answer...?

Answer (score 1):

You’ve already accepted an answer, but you asked a follow-up question in the comments, and leftroundabout, who knows a lot more about this site than me, suggested I make my reply an answer.

You ask about how to use the result of `mkReadme`, which has type `IO Html`, in the program.  That threw me for a loop the first time I ran into the same problem, and that program ended up a real mess because of it.  Here’s what I figured out.

One way you can think about the `IO` monad—not the details of how it works, but why it exists, and when you need it—is that it wraps results that come from the outside world, and therefore need to be synchronized.  So `readFile` needs to read from the outside world, and its result is an `IO Text`, then `markdown` depends on that result and returns a `Html` parse tree, so that result depends on information from outside, and needs to be an `IO Html`.  Then whatever depends on that result ends up being `IO` something-or-other too, and the monad propagates through the entire program.

So here’s how you stop that from happening and keep it confined to `main`.  Here’s a `main` routine we could add to leftroundabout’s answer:

```
{- Needs: text, markdown -}

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TIO
import Text.Blaze.Html (Html)
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Text (renderHtml)
import Text.Markdown (def, markdown)

mkReadme :: IO Html
mkReadme = do
  readmeFile <- TIO.readFile "../README.md"
  return $ markdown def readmeFile

main :: IO ()
main = do
  htmlVersion <- mkReadme -- Type signature is :: IO Html
  let plainText = renderHtml htmlVersion -- Type is :: Html -> Text
  TIO.putStrLn plainText -- Type signature is :: Text -> IO ()
```

The first line of `main` binds an `IO Html` variable.  The second uses it in a pure function that accepts a `Html` and returns a `Text`, which is actually *lifted* to the `IO` monad between the lines thanks to the `do` notation.  The third passes the `Text` to a function that takes `Text` and returns `IO ()`.

If you need to turn a pure function into a monadic one, use `Control.Monad.LiftM`, and if you need to wrap a pure variable as a monadic value, use `return`.

If you want to know what the compiler is really doing, here’s another way to write it:

```
main = mkReadme >>=
       return . renderHtml >>=
       TIO.putStrLn
```

Each `>>=` operator passes the output of the previous function, wrapped in an `IO` monad, to the next function in the chain.  The `return` wraps the output of a pure function in an `IO` monad so it can be bound.

That program dumps the converted Markdown file as HTML to standard output.  Replace the last line with whatever you want to do with the `Html` value you get back from `Markdown`, and you can pretend it isn’t `IO`.

Comment: Worth noting that the common pattern of `mkReadme >>= return . renderHtml` is usually written with `fmap`/`<$>`, i.e., `renderHtml <$> mkReadme`.

Comment: @JonPurdy Good point!  I was trying to do a direct line-by-line translation that used only `Monad` operations, because that’s closer to what `do` notation represents, but you could use applicative style or the `Functor` instance of `IO` as well. I mean, `do` notation exists because writing with `Monads` is otherwise pretty clunky!